# unique search and replace

Tags: excel, csv, vim

I have a csv with two columns. If I import this csv into excel I end up with column A and column B.

Column A contains a string of text eg: 1234 (each row has a unique value)
column B contains a string of text eg: abcd1234

I need to remove the text from column B that is contained in column A. Each row has unique data so an example would look like so:

```
1234, abcd1234,
5678, efgh5678,
9876, ijkl9876,
```

What I want to end up with is:

```
1234, abcd,
5678, efgh,
9876, ijkl,
```

Any ideas I'm happy to process in excel of with command line.

Comment: In cell C1: `=SUBSTITUTE(B1,A1,"")`.

Comment: why do it during import? csv import in excel is a pretty basic thing. load the data, THEN do your changes once it's loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vim, you can do this via `:substitute`, capturing the first column, and those parts of the second column that don't match the first value (referenced via `\1`). I'll let the match start on the second column (with `\zs`); this avoids re-referencing the first column in the replacement part, which just consists of the stuff before (`\2`; not present in your example text), and after (`\3`) the repeated part from column 1.

```
:%substitute/^\([^,]\+\),\zs\([^,]*\)\1\([^,]*\)/\2\3/
```

The `[^,]` stands for any characters inside a column, assuming a simple CSV format.